# Get access token of evenote with node js

Tags: node.js, oauth, cloud, access-token, evernote

I want to read my notes from evernote using OAuth API.

I could generate `oauthToken`, `oauthTokenSecret` and `oauth_verifier`.

I followed https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php

When I try to get access token :

```
 client.getAccessToken(
    oauthToken,
    oauthTokenSecret,
    oauth_verifier,
    function (
      error: any,
      oauthToken: string,
      oauthTokenSecret: string,
      results: any
    ) {
      console.log(oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret, results);
      if (error) {
        // do your error handling
        console.log("Error");

        if (error?.data) fs.writeFile("index.html", error?.data, () => {});
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log(error);
        var authenticatedClient = new Evernote.Client({
          token: oauthToken,
          sandbox: false,
          china: false,
        });
        var noteStore = authenticatedClient.getNoteStore();
        noteStore.listNotebooks().then(function (notebooks: any) {
          console.log(notebooks); // the user's notebooks!
        });
      }
    }
  );
```

I have:

> "Oops, we encountered an error.  Sorry, we've encountered an unexpected error."